# How should we apply the salt to the password?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-management, salt, hmac

According to [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables)

> A rainbow table is ineffective against one-way hashes that include large salts. For example, consider a password hash that is generated using the following function (where "||" is the concatenation operator):
>   `saltedhash(password) = hash(password || salt)`
>   Or
>   `saltedhash(password) = hash(hash(password) || salt)`

Say I'm using Argon2(di) to store passwords. Should I use the second method or first method to hash passwords?
And as a more general question, which hash method is typically better in password storage situations? (What about other situations like HMACS?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I'm using Argon2(di) to store passwords. Should I use the second method or first method to hash passwords?

No. Argon2 takes the salt as a separate argument from the password, and takes responsibility internally about how to incorporate them both into the computation.  As any specialized password hashing function should.

Ideally, though, you should use a higher-level API that takes care of salt generation and management internally, by encapsulating the use of the password hash with:

- An "enrollment" function that takes a password, generates a salt, and outputs a verification string that encapsulates choice of hashing algorithm, algorithm parameters, salt and hash.  See for example the [`password_hash()` in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).
- A "verification" function that takes a password and verification string, parses the latter to recover all those parameters, and verifies that the password matches.  See, e.g., [`password_verify()` in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Basically, if you're manually concatenating salts and passwords like your quote from Wikipedia suggests, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm definitely not. I'm using Argon2's salt parameter for security. As a separate question: what should I do if I have two salts? Since Argon2 only has one salt input, we get back to the concatenation problem again.

Comment: It should be OK to concatenate the two salts into a composite one. If just one of them is unpredictable to an attacker before they see it, so will be the composite.